# Having trouble finding distinct records using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

let's assume i have a table with records like **[{fruit : apple, colour : green, price : 100 },{fruit : apple, colour : red, price : 75},{fruit : banana, colour : yellow, price : 50}]**.

What would be the sequelize command if i wanted to fetch unique fruits, but i want to fetch only the colour field along with it, and i want only 1 occurance of a fruit... So for this table, i want my output to be **[{fruit : apple, colour : green},{fruit : banana, colour : yellow}]**

This is what I tried :

```
fruitVendor.findAndCountAll({
attributes:[[Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('fruit')),'FRUIT'],['colour','COLOUR']]
})
```

But i got **[{fruit : apple, colour : green},{fruit : apple, colour : red},{fruit : banana, colour : yellow}]**

And then i removed colour as one of the attributes just to check if distinct was working fine:

```
fruitVendor.findAndCountAll({
attributes:[[Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('fruit')),'FRUIT']
})
```

And i got **[{fruit : apple},{fruit : banana}]**

So even if i mention distinct with one specific attribute, it applied it to the others as well?

Can anyone help me get **[{fruit : apple, colour : green},{fruit : banana, colour : yellow}]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with any color, you can try this.

```js
fruitVendor.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: [['fruit','FRUIT'], [Sequelize.fn('MIN', Sequelize.col('colour')), 'COLOUR']], // Or MAX
    group: 'fruit'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how SELECT DISTINCT works with SQL. It evaluates all the combinations of the columns you chose to select from.

If it didn't do it this way, how would it know that you wanted {fruit: apple, color: green} instead of {fruit: apple, color: red}?

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way i could get just either of the colours, i don't mind which but i need the colour field. Any solution even if it doesn't use SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: You can try writing some code on the server that will filter things to your liking. I'm not aware of any SQL queries that will return the dataset that you desire. Don't take that as gospel though, there may be something you can do with grouping.